# Take one more piece of luggage travelling from Dusseldorf to Yaounde Cameroon

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I would like to have one more piece of luggage travelling from Dusseldorf to Yaounde, Cameroon; what to do? I will travel on 29 September, and I'm in Bielefeld, Germany

Comment: Call the airline?

Comment: Read the conditions, prepare the money.

Comment: @Alain Meli Provided you haven’t already reached the maximum allowance per passenger permitted by your airline, you can normally either book and pay for additional luggage online or you can call the airline.

Comment: As other commenters have said, "one more" than _what?_ Do you have the maximum allowed by the airline (e.g., 10 items), or the most that you can take for free (e.g., one item)? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 3):

I'am assuming you haven't reached the maximum baggage allowance. I would go to the airlines website, log in to "My Trips" or something similar and then add an extra bag to your reservation. Be sure to add the bag for both ways of your trip.

Alternatively you can also do this at the Airport but charges will most likely be higher.

Depending on the airline, this will cost you from 20 $ to 300 $ (in my experience).